# Spinners in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have an AlertDialog with two spinner in its layout, if I don't set up an adapter for those spinners my layout its inflating correctly. (https://goo.gl/boniIK)

But once I attach an adapter to those spinners there's a huge white space below my positive and negative buttons. (https://goo.gl/3aJOlN)

Does anyone has an idea why it's this white space appearing?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is my `sort_filter_dialog.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dialog_content_padding_top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dialog_content_padding_bottom"
    app:columnCount="4"
    app:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/schoolhub_blue">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_content_space"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_rowSpan="2"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/none"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_content_row_height"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:text="@string/sort"/>

    <Spinner
        style="@style/Spinner"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_sort"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/none"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_content_row_height"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_content_space"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_rowSpan="2"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/none"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_content_row_height"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:text="@string/filter"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_filter"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/none"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_content_row_height"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/divider_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/divider_margin"
        app:layout_columnSpan="4"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

And I'm building my `AlertDialog` in a DialogFragment `onCreateDialog` method

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.sort_filter_dialog, null);
    // Set up for sort spinner.
    ArrayAdapter<String> sortAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sortStringArray);
    sortAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner sortSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_sort);
    sortSpinner.setAdapter(sortAdapter);

    // Set up for filter spinner.
    ArrayAdapter<String> filterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item_selected, filterStringArray);
    filterAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner filterSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_filter);
    filterSpinner.setAdapter(filterAdapter);

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.DialogStyle);
    dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.sort_filter_title));
    dialog.setView(view);

    return dialog.create();
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code please.

Comment: @khalafnt I have added my code, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Without posting your code it's hard to guess but I suspect the issue is the way you are inflating the layout. In most cases when you are using an adapter, inflate it like this:</strike>

`view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);`

Comment: @edwollard, khalafnt unfortunately your answer didn't solve my problem ):

Comment: Try `dialog.setView(view, 0, 0, 0, 0)`